# Evitar que portal web se salte el login

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, primefaces

Tengo un portal creado con JSF + Primefaces + Hibernate, tengo mi pantalla de login y al comprobar las credenciales te redirecciona a un datatable.

Cuando le doy logout al portal, me direcciona al login (hasta ahí todo bien) pero si le doy click al back button del navegador me muestra de nuevo el datatable. El otro problema es que si yo pego mi dirección en el navegador 
http://localhost:puerto/AdministrarUsuarios/private/administrarUsuarios.xhtml
se salta el login y entra al datatable. Use está clase, pero no me funciona:

```
@WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

Este es mi ManageBean:

```
@Named(value = "loginManageBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginManageBean {

private String userName;
private String password;

@Inject
private AsesorService asesorService;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void login() throws IOException {

    Boolean res = false;
    res = asesorService.login(userName, password);
    if (res == true) {
        ExternalContext con = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        con.redirect("private/administrarAsesores.xhtml");
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "Credenciales Inválidas"));
    }
}

public void logout() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext con = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) con.getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("../index.xhtml");
}
```

}

Botón `<p:commandButton value="Salir"  action="#{loginManageBean.logout()}" style="float: right" />`

Lo único que me funciona bien es la configuración para matar la sesión cuando se encuentra inactiva.

Comment: Por favor agrega como tienes declarado tu MB  , en tu pagina puedes agregar un preRenderView que valide que exista sesion antes de mostrar, de lo contrario redirigir a  vista de login.

Comment: Ya está el ManageBean.

Comment: Intenta  agregando en tu XHTML administrarAsesores.xhtml un preRenderView que valide que exista sesión activa. Esto evitara que se muestre si la sesión es nula  o no tiene un usuario logueado con permisos. Para el retroceso  desde el explorador, podrías echar un vistazo con JS. No tengo a la mano laptop para replicar tu código, en cuanto lo tenga publico más.

Comment: Al parecer el preRenderView no funciona hasta ahora.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega como estas colocando el preRenderView. Técnicamente al hacer logout, si pegas directo la url de administrarAreas, se ejecutara tu meto que valide que exista sesión, de  lo contrario redirige a  otra pagina

Comment: Más bien creo que no estoy poniendo los parámetros correctos en el preRenderVier.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60487/discussion-between-gonzalo-leon-and-voiser).

Comment: Ya me quedó, pero gracias por estar al pendiente. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un **HttpSession** que se alimente en cuanto el usuario haga el login, destruirlo al des-loguear y validarlo en el bean de cada página que uses (para que no pueda usar la dirección como explicas en el caso de **...AdministrarUsuarios/private/administrarUsuarios.xhtml**.

Si el usuario es válido generas el HttpSession:

```
HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
session.setAttribute("username", uname);
```

Al momento de des-loguear:

```
HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
session.invalidate();
```

Y si quiere llegar a una página directamente usarías un método como este:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        // Revisa si la variable Session esta configurada.
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession ses = req.getSession(false);
        if (ses != null && ses.getAttribute("username")
           //  El usuario a logueado.
        else   
           //  Se redirecciona al login.xhml.
           res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
    }catch(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println( t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, con todo te adjunto un [enlace](http://www.javaknowledge.info/authentication-based-secure-login-logout-using-jsf-2-0-and-primefaces-3-4-1/) con un tutorial pequeño para su mejor entendimiento. Saludos.

Comment: Segui el tutorial que me proporcionas (obvio no al pie de la letra) más tu respuesta simplificando el tuto y con eso salió, gracias. De verdad te lo agradezco. Un abrazo!

Comment: Excelente, de nada!

Comment: También añadí en el login.xhtml este código en el `<head>`: `<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.forward(-1);
</script>`

Comment: Oh muy bien! Que conseguiste exactamente?

Comment: Al hacer logout y querer regresar con el back button no te lo permite (te sigue direccionando al login) y al pegar la dirección completa igual te direcciona al login.

Comment: Ya veo, excelente aportación @GonzaloLeón! Omití esa puerta.